# Can AppleTV stream content directly from iTunes in Windows

Tags: itunes, windows, appletv

Suppose I have iTunes in a Windows laptop. Can AppleTV stream the content from that iTunes directly (as it is supposed to do with iTunes in a Mac) ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple you should be able to as long as they are on the same Home Sharing network.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12352